# Разместить HBox с помощью StackPane

Tags: javafx

Нужно написать простой графический интерфейс для программы нахождения корня уравнения методом половинного деления. В центре окна находятся 3 TextField, а снизу кнопка для начала обсчета и Label для вывода результата. Я планировал для начала создать два HBox, запихнуть в один все что должно быть в центре, а во второй все что внизу. Затем с помощью StackPane разместить первый HBox в центре, а второй внизу. И при выполнении заметил что они вообще не меняют места. Получается что в javafx одними layout нельзя менять меся других layout, или я что-то не так сделал, и нужно это сделать другим способом.

P. S. Знаю что если не написать "и быстро" будут понижать рейтинг, поэтому **И БЫСТРО**

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TextField leftLimitTextField = new TextField("Enrer left limit");
        TextField rightLimitTextField = new TextField("Enter right limit");
        TextField mistakeTextField = new TextField("0.0001");

        HBox metodOfDivisionSpecification = new HBox(leftLimitTextField,
                rightLimitTextField, mistakeTextField);

        Label result = new Label("Here be result");
        Button startCalculationButton = new Button("Start calculation");
        //TODO: button event listener
        HBox calculationsPanel = new HBox(startCalculationButton, result);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        root.getChildren().addAll(metodOfDivisionSpecification, calculationsPanel);
        StackPane.setAlignment(metodOfDivisionSpecification, Pos.CENTER);
        StackPane.setAlignment(calculationsPanel, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, что в этой ситуации нужен [javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html)
StackPane не про это, он для размещение компонентов поверх друг друга.